# Excluding style from QSpinBoxes in QColorDialog when using QSS to style QAbstractSpinBox

Tags: css, qt, qtstylesheets

I have been styling a Qt desktop application with QSS using Jorgen-VikingGod's excellent [Qt-Frameless-Window-DarkStyle](https://github.com/Jorgen-VikingGod/Qt-Frameless-Window-DarkStyle) as a baseline. Unfortunately, we also have to support a rather dated tablet device (that runs Windows) in the field, meaning the tiny spin box buttons were effectively unusable to some of our customers.

A suggested solution was to create large +/- buttons and put them on opposite sides of the spin box:

[image: SpinBox with big buttons]

However, this yields bad behavior with certain Qt convenience controls, such as `QColorDialog`:

[image: Bad QColorDialog]

My QSS code is as follows:

```
QAbstractSpinBox {
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(38,38,38,255);
}
QAbstractSpinBox:focus {
  border-color: palette(highlight);
}
QAbstractSpinBox::up-button {
  subcontrol-origin: border;
  subcontrol-position: center right;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-image: url(:/darkstyle/icon_spin_box_button.png);
  margin-left: 1px;
}
QAbstractSpinBox::down-button {
  subcontrol-origin: border;
  subcontrol-position: center left;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-image: url(:/darkstyle/icon_spin_box_button.png);
  margin-right: 1px;
}
QAbstractSpinBox::up-button:pressed {
  border-image: url(:/darkstyle/icon_spin_box_button_pressed.png);
}
QAbstractSpinBox::down-button:pressed {
  border-image: url(:/darkstyle/icon_spin_box_button_pressed.png);
}
QAbstractSpinBox::up-arrow {
  image: url(:/darkstyle/icon_spin_box_plus_sign.png);
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
QAbstractSpinBox::down-arrow {
  image: url(:/darkstyle/icon_spin_box_minus_sign.png);
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
QAbstractSpinBox::up-arrow:disabled,
QAbstractSpinBox::up-arrow:off {
  image: url(:/darkstyle/icon_spin_box_plus_sign_disabled.png);
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
QAbstractSpinBox::down-arrow:disabled,
QAbstractSpinBox::down-arrow:off {
  image: url(:/darkstyle/icon_spin_box_minus_sign_disabled.png);
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
```

So far, I have tried replacing the `QAbstractSpinBox` selectors with `.QSpinBox, .QDoubleSpinBox`, but that yielded a mess that looked like a hybrid of the default style (up/down arrows stacked on the right) with my style (dark borders, raised appearance, etc).

It doesn't appear that QSS supports the CSS3-style `:not` selector, nor does it provide an equivalent that I can use.

With all that said, is there any manner for me to apply this style to every spin box in my application EXCEPT those in `QColorDialog`? Or any alternative that doesn't involve me setting this style by ID/objectName on every single instance of spin box that I have in my application? Looking through the source code, it appears that the `QColorDialog` uses a `QSpinBox`-derived class named `QColSpinBox`, so if I can exclude a specific subclass, then that would also be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style some of the components of the QColorDialog with CSS/QSS.

[image]

So you can add something like this:

```
QColorDialog QSpinBox {
    min-width: 3.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

to add some extra scpace to the spin boxes. I add also **min-width** and **min-height** to **QColorDialog QColorPicker** like this:

```
QColorDialog QColorPicker {
    min-width: 20em;
    min-height: 20em;
    border: solid 1px gray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm going to test this out tomorrow and will accept it as the answer if it works out. I had just about abandoned hope on getting an answer to this.

Comment: You can also change the style back to `auto` or `inherit` if you like. I found your question because I had the same problem 2 days ago. Yesterday I found this solution by reading the Qt-Sourcecode ... so I came back :)

Comment: I decided to go with your original answer and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the starting point !!! After a very long fight with Qt 5.9.2 I found how to revert Push Buttons to their default / native state:

`QColorDialog QPushButton {background-color:native; color:native; border: native; border-radius:-1px; padding: native;}`

No **auto** nor **default** value here.

**native** is the key but, for the border and background you have to cancel any **border-radius** because of the following code:

```
void QStyleSheetStyle::drawComplexControl(ComplexControl cc, const QStyleOptionComplex *opt, QPainter *p,
                                          const QWidget *w) const
{
    RECURSION_GUARD(baseStyle()->drawComplexControl(cc, opt, p, w); return)

    QRenderRule rule = renderRule(w, opt);

    switch (cc) {
    case CC_ComboBox:
        if (const QStyleOptionComboBox *cmb = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionComboBox *>(opt)) {
            QStyleOptionComboBox cmbOpt(*cmb);
            cmbOpt.rect = rule.borderRect(opt->rect);
            if (rule.hasNativeBorder()) {
                rule.drawBackgroundImage(p, cmbOpt.rect);
                rule.configurePalette(&cmbOpt.palette, 
            ...
            ...
            ...

... ... ...
bool hasNativeBorder() const {
    return bd == 0
           || (!bd->hasBorderImage() && bd->styles[0] == BorderStyle_Native);
}
... ... ... 
void QRenderRule::fixupBorder(int nativeWidth)
{
if (bd == 0)
    return;

if (!bd->hasBorderImage() || bd->bi->pixmap.isNull()) {
    bd->bi = 0;
    // ignore the color, border of edges that have none border-style
    QBrush color = pal ? pal->foreground : QBrush();
    const bool hasRadius = bd->radii[0].isValid() || bd->radii[1].isValid()
                           || bd->radii[2].isValid() || bd->radii[3].isValid();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if ((bd->styles[i] == BorderStyle_Native) && hasRadius)
            bd->styles[i] = BorderStyle_None;
```

Even if you tell to set border to **native** it will fall back to **none** if you have previously setup a border radius...
Yous have to give an invalid value for radius. Radius is stored un QSize which is invalid for -1, -1, -1, -1.

**none** will make **hasNativeBorder** failed leading to no border / background at all...

Why not a simple **qt-all-native: true** or similar QSS extension...